# MariaDB response from Insert Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb

I am currently building a small application and everything worked so far, but now I am really confused about a return value.

I am using a MariaDB Database with NodeJS and the mariadb connector. All the statements pass without failure, but when I send an INSERT Statement, the DB sends back this:

```
OkPacket {affectedRows: 1, insertId: 51n, warningStatus: 0}
affectedRows:
1
insertId:
51n
warningStatus:
0
```

The Database is fine with the statement, but I don't get where the "n" behind the inserted ID is coming. The problem is, it breaks the complete application, because JSON.stringify() says:

```
TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {stack: 'TypeError: Do not  know how to serialize a Big…ions (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)', message: 'Do not know how to serialize a BigInt'}
```

So it seems, that the DB sends back the ID, which is the primary key of this table, as a BigInteger and JSON.stringify() can not parse this. But I don't want a BigInteger in the response.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass options to the query method of the connection to return the `insertId` as string.

```js
await conn.query(stmt, { supportBigNumbers: true, bigNumberStrings: true})
```

Alternately, you can return it as a `Number`. The method throws an exception if the `insertId` [can't be converted from a BigInt to a Number](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/3.0.1/lib/cmd/command.js#L127)

```js
await conn.query(stmt, { supportBigNumbers: true, insertIdAsNumber: true})
```

Comment: Thx very much. You saved me. After reading your answer, I found those options in the documentation of the connector so it seems, that I was just too stupid to read. But thx again.